# Addition in php echo

Tags: php

Whats wrong with this code.i am getting this + 200 +.i just want addiiton in this.+ sign creating problem in echo

```
<?php echo "<div id=totalValu>Total Value: <span id=totalValue style=float:right>$ $beg + $int + $adv </span></div> "; ?>
```

Comment: You need to wrap your attributes in quotes, eg: `id='totalValue'`. I'm not sure if that's causing the problem, but you should be doing that anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to break out the addition from the string literal as follows:

```
<?php echo '<div id="totalValu">Total Value: <span id="totalValue" style="float:right">$'.($beg + $int + $adv).'</span></div>'; ?>
```